# Migrating from create-app-app to usual react application

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Recently I started working on a commercial project that was written by another programmer basing on the create-react-app. Since the project is already big enough and does not stop developing, working with the create-react-app is becoming more and more inconvenient, because I want to be able to completely configure myself webpack, node.js and other packages.

I'm looking for an opportunity as quickly as possible to migrate the project from create-react-app to the form, as if the project was originally written without it.

To work with the code after `npm run eject` seemed to me unreasonably complex.

I am trying to find at least some instructions or guides on this issue but did not find it yet.

Here's the package.json dependencies:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.17",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-collapse": "^4.0.3",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-facebook-login": "^3.7.2",
    "react-google-login": "^2.11.3",
    "react-input-mask": "^1.2.2",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-scrollchor": "^4.2.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.14.11",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^1.6.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "validator": "^8.2.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "react-scrolllock": "^3.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "stylelint": "^9.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of `create-react-app` is to hide and simplify  complexities of webpack and other enhanced dependencies(Like babel)

Comment: Hey Darya, which other dependencies does your project have, e.g. react-redux, react-router-dom? Including a package.json in your question will help to give you better advise.

Comment: Hey Roy, thank you for the feedback! I added dependencies to the initial question.

Comment: What you want to do is a bad idea. You already say it's complex after ejecting. What do you think will happen after couple of months? Your configurations will be too complex for next engineers

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends what you want to do.  I had the same problem. I ejected my local copy and found I got a lot of problems.  My solution was the take the existing CRA project ad do the following:

1. Update to latest react and react-dom , run 'yarn react@next react-dom@next'
2. You should now have the latest react versions - so you can code split using React.lazy/React.Suspense, use hooks and so on.
3. If you have an issue with errors when using the import syntax you need to use the babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import plugin. Put the "babel" field in your package json.

I hope that is some help. There are also libraries like https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired but I haven't used them.